# Design "Text Messaging" .NET component that supports multiple vendors

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture

I have a .NET web application that needs to have text messaging gateway feature implemented; i.e., sending text messages, using third-party vendors. The web app currently deployed to multiple countries with the same code-base and different web.config for each country.

What is the best architecture strategy and design pattern to use to create a **business component** that will support different text messaging gateway providers/vendors taking into consideration the following:

1. Each country will ideally have its own text messaging gateway vendor.
2. Each vendor provides its own specific way of calling its API; i.e. parameters, api location, security ... etc.
3. The ability for one country to change its text messaging gateway vendor anytime with minimum overhead and modifications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) here.  Create an interface that looks something like the following:

```
public interface ITextMessageStrategy{
    void Send(TextMessage message)
}
```

You'll have a concrete implementation for each vendor.  You mentioned that each vendor will have different parameters for their API.  The key to making this work is passing an object (TextMessage in my example) that contains all the data that any vendor might need.  Your configuration will map a country to the full class name of the implementation it will use.  You'll then use reflection to dynamically instantiate the proper text messaging strategy.  If some TextMessageStrategy implementations require constructor parameters or some other complex setup before they are used, consider using the [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) in conjunction.  You see these two patterns together often.

Comment: This pattern is used by Microsoft and others for their "Provider" models, like MembershipProviers, EntityProviders, etc...